# Want to "deal" cards in Swift: how to stop cards from changing sizes as more cards are dealt

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need help with this animation. Basically, I want to deal 12 cards when I tap on the "deck." However, I want to deal it so that the sizes of each card is already set; I don't want the card size to change as more cards come onto screen. Put differently, to put 12 cards on the screen, at the end, we have 3 rows of 4 cards. But the Swift system tries to put 3 cards per row, and then moves to 4 cards per row. This changing of card size looks very weird, so I was hoping to put in some code that makes it so the card size doesn't change.

[image]

[image]

[image]
ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: GameViewModel
    
    @Namespace private var dealingNamespace

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            newGameButton
            gameBody
            HStack {
                deckBody
                discardedDeckBody
            }
            shuffleButton
        }
    }
    
    var newGameButton: some View {
        Button(action: { viewModel.newGame() }) { Text("New Game")
            .font(.caption) }
    }
    
    var gameBody: some View {
        AspectVGrid(items: viewModel.playingCards, aspectRatio: 2/3) { card in
            CardView(viewModel: viewModel, card: card)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.id, in: dealingNamespace)
                .padding(4)
//                .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .identity, removal: .scale))
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        viewModel.choose(card)
                    }
                }
                .foregroundColor(viewModel.borderColor(for: card))
            }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    
    private func dealAnimation(for cardNumber: Int, _ totalCardsToDeal: Int) -> Animation {
        let delay = Double(cardNumber) * (CardConstants.totalDealDuration / Double(totalCardsToDeal))
        return Animation.easeInOut(duration: CardConstants.dealDuration).delay(delay)
    }
    
    var deckBody: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.undealtCards) { card in
                CardView(viewModel: viewModel, card: card)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.id, in: dealingNamespace)
//                    .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .opacity, removal: .identity))
            }
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: DrawingConstants.cornerRadius)
        }
        .frame(width: CardConstants.undealtWidth, height: CardConstants.undealtHeight)
        .foregroundColor(CardConstants.color)
        .onTapGesture {
            for cardNumber in Array(0..<viewModel.numberOfCardsToDeal()) {
                withAnimation(dealAnimation(for: cardNumber, viewModel.numberOfCardsToDeal())) {
                    viewModel.deal()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var discardedDeckBody: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.discardedCards()) { card in
                CardView(viewModel: viewModel, card: card)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: CardConstants.undealtWidth, height: CardConstants.undealtHeight)
        .foregroundColor(CardConstants.color)
    }
    
    private struct CardConstants {
        static let color = Color.red
        static let aspectRatio: CGFloat = 2/3
        static let dealDuration: Double = 0.5
        static let totalDealDuration: Double = 2
        static let undealtHeight: CGFloat = 90
        static let undealtWidth = undealtHeight * aspectRatio
    }
    
    var shuffleButton: some View {
        Button("Shuffle") {
            withAnimation {
                viewModel.shuffle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: GameViewModel

    let card: GameModel.Card
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: DrawingConstants.cornerRadius)
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
                shape.stroke(lineWidth: DrawingConstants.lineWidth)
                viewModel.symbol(for: card)
                .padding(.all)
                shape.foregroundColor(viewModel.cover(for: card))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DrawingConstants {
    static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10
    static let lineWidth: CGFloat = 3
    static let fontScale: CGFloat = 0.7
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let game = GameViewModel()
        ContentView(viewModel: game)
            .previewInterfaceOrientation(.portrait)
    }
}
```

AspectVGrid

```
import SwiftUI

struct AspectVGrid<Item, ItemView>: View where ItemView: View, Item: Identifiable {
    var items: [Item]
    var aspectRatio: CGFloat
    var content: (Item) -> ItemView
    
    init(items: [Item], aspectRatio: CGFloat, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Item) -> ItemView) {
        self.items = items
        self.aspectRatio = aspectRatio
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    let computedWidth: CGFloat = widthThatFits(itemCount: items.count, in: geometry.size, itemAspectRatio: aspectRatio)
                    let width: CGFloat = computedWidth > 65 ? computedWidth : 65
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [adaptiveGridItem(width: width)], spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(items) { item in
                            content(item).aspectRatio(aspectRatio, contentMode: .fit)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func adaptiveGridItem(width: CGFloat) -> GridItem {
        var gridItem = GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: width))
        gridItem.spacing = 0
        return gridItem
    }
    
    private func widthThatFits(itemCount: Int, in size: CGSize, itemAspectRatio: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        var columnCount = 1
        var rowCount = itemCount
        repeat {
            let itemWidth = size.width / CGFloat(columnCount)
            let itemHeight = itemWidth / itemAspectRatio
            if CGFloat(rowCount) * itemHeight < size.height {
                break
            }
            columnCount += 1
            rowCount = (itemCount + (columnCount - 1)) / columnCount
        } while columnCount < itemCount
        if columnCount > itemCount {
            columnCount = itemCount
        }
        return floor(size.width / CGFloat(columnCount))
    }
}
```

Model

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct GameModel {
    
    private(set) var cards: Array<Card>
    
    var undealtCards: Array<Card>
    
    var discardedCards: Array<Card> = []
    
    private(set) var playingCards: Array<Card>
                            
    private var selectedCards: Array<Card> = []
    
    private static var colors = [ContentColor.red, ContentColor.green, ContentColor.purple]
    
    private static var shapes = [ContentShape.squiggly, ContentShape.circle, ContentShape.diamond]
    
    private static var fillings = [ContentFilling.empty, ContentFilling.full, ContentFilling.striped]
    
    private static var numbers = [1, 2, 3]
    
    func numberOfUndealtCards() -> Int {
        return undealtCards.count
    }
    
    mutating func deal() {
        playingCards.append(undealtCards[0])
        undealtCards.remove(at: 0)
    }
    
    func numberOfCardsToDeal() -> Int {
        if numberOfUndealtCards() == 81 {
            return 12
        } else {
            return 3
        }
    }

    mutating func resetCards() {
        if !playingCards.first(where: { $0 == selectedCards.first })!.isMatched! {
            selectedCards.forEach { card in
                let unmatchedIndex = playingCards.firstIndex(of: card)!
                playingCards[unmatchedIndex].isMatched = nil
            }
            selectedCards = []
        } 
    }
    
    mutating func shuffle() {
        playingCards = playingCards.shuffled()
    }
    
    mutating func choose(_ card: Card) {
        if let chosenIndex = playingCards.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == card.id }) {
            
            if selectedCards.count < 3 || selectedCards.count == 3 && !selectedCards.contains(playingCards[chosenIndex]) {

                if selectedCards.count == 3 { resetCards() }

                if !playingCards[chosenIndex].isSelected {
                    playingCards[chosenIndex].isSelected = true
                    selectedCards.append(playingCards[chosenIndex])
                    
                    if selectedCards.count == 4 {
                        let chosenCard = playingCards[chosenIndex]
                        for card in selectedCards {
                            if card != chosenCard {
                                discardedCards.append(card)
                                let matchedIndex = playingCards.firstIndex(of: card)!
                                playingCards.remove(at: matchedIndex)
                            }
                        }
                        selectedCards = [chosenCard]
                    }
                    
                    if selectedCards.count == 3 {
                        if formSet(by: selectedCards) {
                            selectedCards.forEach { card in
                                let index = playingCards.firstIndex(of: card)!
                                playingCards[index].isMatched = true
                                playingCards[index].isSelected = false
                            }
                        } else {
                            selectedCards.forEach { card in
                                let index = playingCards.firstIndex(of: card)!
                                playingCards[index].isMatched = false
                                playingCards[index].isSelected = false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    playingCards[chosenIndex].isSelected = false
                    selectedCards.removeAll(where: { $0 == playingCards[chosenIndex] })
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func formSet(by cards: [Card]) -> Bool {
        return feature(\Card.color, isValidFor: cards) && feature(\Card.shape, isValidFor: cards) && feature(\Card.filling, isValidFor: cards) && feature(\Card.number, isValidFor: cards)
    }

    private func feature<F: Hashable>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Card, F>, isValidFor cards: [Card]) -> Bool {
        let count = cards.reduce(into: Set<F>()) { $0.insert($1[keyPath: keyPath]) }.count
        return count == 1 || count == 3
    }
    
    init() {
        cards = []
        var counter = 0
        for id1 in GameModel.colors.indices {
            for id2 in GameModel.shapes.indices {
                for id3 in GameModel.fillings.indices {
                    for id4 in GameModel.numbers.indices {
                        cards.append(Card(color: GameModel.colors[id1], shape: GameModel.shapes[id2], filling: GameModel.fillings[id3], number: GameModel.numbers[id4], id: counter))
                        counter += 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        playingCards = []
        undealtCards = cards
    }
    
    enum ContentColor {
        case red
        case green
        case purple
    }
    
    enum ContentShape {
        case squiggly
        case circle
        case diamond
    }
    
    enum ContentFilling {
        case empty
        case full
        case striped
    }
    
    struct Card: Identifiable, Equatable {
        var color: ContentColor
        var shape: ContentShape
        var filling: ContentFilling
        var number: Int
        var id: Int
        var isSelected = false
        var isUndealt = false
        var isMatched: Bool?
        
        static func == (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
                return lhs.id == rhs.id
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to help. You are using a bunch of customized views without showing us anything beside rows of letter. I can't even see what is inside your Grid, Model, Value of card width/height. I would assume something is wrong with your Grid which you did not set limit item per row, or something is wrong with your declared card width/height.

Comment: @tail I added some more code. I'll look into what you said.

Comment: The problem seems to be the LazyVGrid inside your AspectVGrid.  LazyVGrid(columns: [adaptiveGridItem(width: width)] <- the number of your item per row here is 1+, so it can be any number. Also, the width that you give to the adaptiveGridItem should be ensured that it may fill the screen width after 3 cards are displayed.

Comment: If each of your card width is 0.26 - 0.3 percentage of the screen width, the maximum of 3 cards will be guaranteed.

Comment: @tail My LazyVGrid is designed such that my cards get smaller and smaller the more cards you put in, but I do have a minumum card width of 65. So I think Swift is doing what I'm telling it to: when it first deals, the cards are large because there's a lot of space, but as cards fill the screen, they then get smaller. My question is how do I get it so that their final size is dealt from the start?

Comment: You want the card size to be 65 since the start?

Comment: @tail Essentially, I want my cards to change size - get smaller - as more cards enter the screen. I set a minimum width of 65; if they want to get smaller, instead revert to scroll view. The problem is that when I deal the cards one at a time, since there's a lot of screen real estate for card1, it sets the width to say 100. Since there's less screen real estate for the second card, it sets it to 90, but since the size of card 2 must equal size of card 1, card1 changes to 90. Then the same thing happens for card3: it's size 80, which changes card1 and card2

Comment: This leads to a very weird animation. Cards are dealt large, but as more enter the screen, they get smaller. I want it so that when 12 cards are dealt, swift knows in advance the exact size it should use for those 12 cards

Answer (score 0):

Code is untestable and unclear due to missed many components, but the issue is because use use `withAnimation`, like

```
.onTapGesture {
    withAnimation {
        viewModel.choose(card)
    }
}
```

which animates everything animatable.

There are next directions to fix observed behavior

1. disable animations everywhere they are unneeded, for example animating of frames

   ```
    .frame(width: CardConstants.undealtWidth, height: CardConstants.undealtHeight)
    .animation(nil, value: viewModel.undealtCards) // << like this !!
    .foregroundColor(CardConstants.color)
   ```
2. remove all explicit generic `withAnimation` and use `animation(_, value)` specifically in those places which are going to be animatable, like

   ```
    VStack {
        newGameButton
        gameBody
        HStack {
            deckBody
            discardedDeckBody
        }
        shuffleButton
    }
    .animation(.default, value: viewModel.playingCards)   // << here !!
   ```
3. probably combine 1-2